# Convert Png in Base64 on Android for RestApi with android.gesture.GestureOverlayView

Tags: android, base64, android-gesture

I created a Restful service in php for save data in my mysql db.
Now I'm developing native Android app that use my API for save a image in db.
but I would format image in **PNG and convert in Base64** but **adding data:image/png;base64** because it's format that I need for webApp.

I created this **activity.xml**

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
       android:id="@+id/signaturePad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"
        android:fadeEnabled="false"
        android:gestureColor="#333"
        android:gestureStrokeLengthThreshold="0.1"
        android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
        android:fadeOffset="5000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="testImage"
        android:text="test"/>
```

And on my **Activity.java**

```
public void testImage(View v) throws IOException {
    GestureOverlayView gestureView = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.signaturePad);
    assert gestureView != null;
    gestureView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(gestureView.getDrawingCache());
    String signature = bitmapToBase64(bm);

    Log.e("base64", signature);
}

private String bitmapToBase64(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);

    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.URL_SAFE);
}
```

I can i append simply to return string **data:image/png;base64,** but are there a better method for this operation?

Comment: Do you have any problems doing so? We suppose you tested this already! What you do looks ok to me.

Comment: Thankyou, no I'havent problem but I was wondering if there was another way to do this.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind why you upload a .png base64 encoded. You could as well upload the bytes array that contains the .png directly. Less bytes to transfer. Well your server schould accept such of course.